# to vertically align text in center in table when other cells are rotated

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to move first cell text "Assembly" to the center of cell. I already tried raisebox, parbox and many more things but nothing worked. Please help me. And, I don't want to change the rotation of other cells.

```
    \newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Assembly & \rot{Contigs} & \rot{Largest contig} & \rot{Total length} & 
    \rot{Misassemblies} & \rot{Local misassemblies} & \rot{Mismatches per 100KB} &
    \rot{N50} & \rot{Predicted genes} & \rot{Genome fraction (\%)}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image: current latex output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `multirow` with a height correction works. I removed the `\arraystretch=1.4` as it didn't do anything here (maybe you need it for your real table) and used `\multirowcell` from the `makecell` package, as the syntax is slightly simpler, and the package has commands to add vertical padding to cells (`\gape'…}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{1}[11ex]{Assembly}& \rot{Contigs} & \rot{Largest contig} & \rot{Total length} &
    \rot{Misassemblies} & \rot{Local misassemblies} &\gape[t]{\rot{Mismatches per 100KB}} &
    \rot{N50} & \rot{Predicted genes} & \rot{Genome fraction (\%)}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than `\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}`, I'd write `\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}`.

Comment: @Mico: I reused the O.P.'s code for this one, but it works. Is there any drawback?

Comment: The OP's code for the `\rot` macro just happens to work as (a) the underlying `\rotatebox` macro expects two arguments and (b) `\rot` is being followed by a braces-delimited expression in all instances. The main advantage, in my view, of specifying explicitly that `\rot` takes exactly one argument is that it simplifies debugging, should a user ever forget to provide an argument for `\rot`.

Comment: I see. 'Tis corrected. Thanks for the  information!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\rotatebox{90}` you can use `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}` to rotate boxes around their centers

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Assembly & \rot{Contigs} & \rot{Largest contig} & \rot{Total length} & 
    \rot{Misassemblies} & \rot{Local misassemblies} & \rot{Mismatches per 100KB} &
    \rot{N50} & \rot{Predicted genes} & \rot{Genome fraction (\%)}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]